# How to simplify the function F = AB'C' +A'B'C' + A'BC' + A'B'C

Tags: boolean

I want to simplify the function F = AB'C' +A'B'C' + A'BC' + A'B'C,
but I do not know how to do it,
I can only simplify it as B'C' + A'BC' + A'B'C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably easiest if you write down the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and see how best to cover the 1s.